# Converter from IP based cameras to Flash player

Tags: converters, codec, ip-camera, flashplayer-10, formats

I would like to know the file formats that IP based surveillance cameras produces. I would then need to build or use available codec/ source code to convert to a format Flash player 10 can support. These are formats other than the usual .FLV for my website which is run on JBoss with Flex 3. I would like to support as many file formats as possible.

I do not want to introduce a streaming server (FMS or RED5 Open source) because of various reasons.

Have anyone any idea about this? Any help would be amazing to get because I have not done anything like this before.

Thanks in advance,
Ranjith

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to expect these to be standard or consistent; they can do anything they want as long as the camera and the base station agree.

You would have to acquire the target surveillance system and read its documentation, or sniff its network traffic and see what it does.  If the first brand seems too difficult, move on to another brand.

Comment: Actually I do not have control about the formats or cameras the client may be using. My intention is to support as many formats as possible at the end of the day. Thanks for your reply.